# Swift app debugging: call to NSWorkspace.shared.open on OSX 10.15 denied

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, macos-catalina

I have a piece of code, which opens a folder in finder:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: outputDir))
```

Under Catalina (OSX 10.15), this access is denied. I need special rights for this app. But how can I do this? I opened Security settings and added my compiled app to "Full Disk access" and "Files and folders" (I'm using a german OS; so text may differ!)
Whenever I rebuild my app, is it the same app or how can I debug without assigning the newly created app again and again?
Professional apps offer a managed tour for the user to drop their own app icon into the security area. Is this available anywhere as code, so I can use it too?